# To convert/merge/concat a pandas dictionary dataframes into one massive dataframe with reduced processing time (code efficiency)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, iteration

I have 3750 dataframes in a dictionary, each having 500-550 rows adding up to 1.8M records if we merge them.

I am looking to merge/concat 3750 dataframes in a dictionary into one massive pandas Dataframe with 1.8M to 1.9M total records.

Currently, my code takes forever to run and I am sure is not efficient at all: (also I am trying to index one of the columns for efficiency, but its not helping).

```
# pdf_dict is the pandas dictionary with 3750 dataframes

# convert your dictionary to a list
list_dataframes = pdf_dict.values()
# keep the dictionary keys with the same order, in case you will need them
list_dataframes_keys = pdf_dict.keys()

# if the date is not the index
df = pd.concat([x.set_index('order_date') for x in list_dataframes], axis=1)
# if the date is the index
df = pd.concat([x for x in list_dataframes], axis=1)
```

Also not sure if 'concat' function would be efficient enough for the data size.

```
df = pd.concat(pd_dct.values())
```

Sample dictionary would be as below:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":['val1','val3'],
    "col2":['val2','val3'],
    "col3":['val3','val5']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":['val7','val3'],
    "col2":['val2','val3'],
    "col3":['val3','val5']
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1":['val10','val3'],
    "col2":['val12','val3'],
    "col3":['val13','val5']
})

pd_dct = {"A": df1, "B": df2, "C": df3}
```

Any guidance is highly valued, please help.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Please provide a sample dictionary to work with.

Comment: @HimanshuPanwar, i have added a sample dictionary with 3 dfs in my question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pd.concat(pd_dct.values(),ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Hi @himanshu, i was also looking for reducing the time taken to convert 1.9M records. I have tried this code previously and it takes a long time.